# Console application - masked password input

Tags: macos, swift, console-application

I'm working on console application for OS X. It is native application in Xcode in swift. User is going to provide his personal password into console. This is one-time action, when password is provided, it is stored by application into KeyChain.

I would like to support user with secure password input. For reading username I use readLine(). I don't want to use same for password as:

- Password is visible when user is typing it.
- When user press enter, it is still visible on screen.

So far I have 2 ideas how can I prompt for password securely:

- Use some kind of ReadChar() function and after each key press, clear console screen, so letter entered by user will not be visible on screen.
- Force readLine() function to mask entered characters.

I was not able to find any function that can capture one customisation entered by user. Also I was not able to identify function that I can use to clear console screen. For second idea: In Apple development documentation, I was not able to find any function that will mask user input.

Can you please advice how to overcome this challenge?